# Reading Multiple Variables from a flat file

Tags: nodes, ros

I am trying to read the variables from a flat file. I am implementing a ROS node. So, currently I am reading only the variable LOB from the flat file and I made a node for it. My question is if I want to read the GPS variable data from the flat file can I code it in the same ROS node I made for LOB variable or I have to make another node ?

```
$90LOB238   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB280   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB261   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB219   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB204   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB270   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB244   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB236   0   0   6 10  &
$90TM020516 18552200&
$90LOB246   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB259   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB192   0   0   6 10  &
RSSI $90LOB213   0   0   5 10  &
$90LOB220   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB264   0   0   6 10  &
$90LOB238   0   0   5 10  &
$90LOB344   0   0   5 10  &
$90GPSA7   0   38281248  -77448408&
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in the same node, because both actions serve the same objective in your application. As you can see in the documentation : http://wiki.ros.org/Nodes, they do say nodes are meant to operate at a fine-grained scale, but not as fine as you propose. So, yes, you should put the two parsings in the same node.